# “The given path's format is not supported.” only for certain file paths

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, file-upload, path

These are my troubles: When uploading from any other file location this works. However if I try to upload these files, I can't seem to get past the error.

C:\Users\User\OneDrive - TEAM\2021\Libra\Doc. complete contract TEST - Client 17-06-2021.pdf

C:\Users\User\OneDrive - TEAM\Client\2021\doc12719720210701124854 complete contract.pdf

I can't seem to notice any illegal characthers here ... Please help.

The function:

```
    {

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {

            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files/"), file.FileName);


            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(path);
            }
            try
            {

                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.LogError(string.Format("Unexpected error"));
            }

            return file.FileName;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that you can access OneDrive files that way--you need to authenticate. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onedrive-concept-overview,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/?view=odsp-graph-online and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/sample-code?view=odsp-graph-online

Comment: Two things. 1) OneDrive locations have some magic associated with them (since they are sync-ed to the web in the background). I'm not sure what the magic is, but it is curse provoking at times. 2) take the path and use a UTF8 encoding to turn it into a byte array. See if there's any badness hiding in there